# PHP SQL UPDATE broken?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make an update query to update a user to have a password.  The update statement is extremely easy and it has been baffling me for about 12 hours now.

I have read everything having to do with this on 3.5 pages of google searches. but for some reason, none of the suggestions work for me!

Here is the UPDATE query in its 'original' form:

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE users_sensitive SET password = '$password_hash', ch_password = '$password_hash' WHERE email_hash = '$email_hash'";
$result_update = mysql_query($sql_update) or die(mysql_error());
```

When I do this update Query, I get no errors or anything back.  It also just does not update.

Here's another rendition of the same code:

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE users_sensitive SET password = '" . $password_hash . "', ch_password = '" . $password_hash. "' WHERE email_hash = '" . $email_hash . "'";
$result_update = mysql_query($sql_update) or die(mysql_error());
```

Again, nothing happens.

When I put the actual numbers in here instead of the php variables:

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE users_sensitive SET password = '700b5b23b511d974fe9eeb17ad350b33', ch_password = '700b5b23b511d974fe9eeb17ad350b33' WHERE email_hash = 'ac24dab060a172d8c0b3679d8ae61cac'";
$result_update = mysql_query($sql_update) or die(mysql_error());
```

(don't worry, it's not sensitive info) It does actually update...

So, I'm assuming my syntax is wrong?  I know these are Strings instead of just numbers, so I need the single quotes around them.  I have the two variables I need echoed and they are both showing exactly what they should be.  I have even tried to use backticks around the column name but that didn't do anything?

I did a var_dump and it came back "true".

When I do a print on my $sql_update, I get:

```
UPDATE users_sensitive SET password = '700b5b23b511d974fe9eeb17ad350b33', ch_password = '700b5b23b511d974fe9eeb17ad350b33' WHERE email_hash = 'ac24dab060a172d8c0b3679d8ae61cac'
```

There is no whitespace here. 
When I print the $result_update, it comes up with: 1

**ANSWER**
Thank you to bemace, James Anderson, VolkerK, alex and the others!

The problem was that there was a strange line break in the code creating whitespace that was not the same as on the database.

After backtracking, I noticed at the very beginning of my code on this page, I used a GET to get a hash number from the URL. While making a variable, during testing, I added a line break to the variable for testing purposes only. I (stupidly) left the line break in there. When using that variable in a hidden form field, it included the line break.

After taking the line break out of the first line, everything matched up and all is good.

If you are reading this and plan on posting later, Posting the entire code is probably worth it. This problem would have been fixed earlier if I had.

Again, Thank you to the quick responses and trouble shooting!

Comment: You have used `mysql_real_escape_string()` on those variables before interpolating them?

Comment: Did you check the variables in the where condition to fit your expectations ?

Comment: What it says `var_dump($result_update)`?

Comment: Did you actually print out `$sql_update` and not just the variables? What does `$result_update` contain (true?)? What does `mysql_affected_rows()` say?

Comment: Try a `var_dump($sql_update)` perhaps?

Comment: You should temporarily include `echo $sql_update` so you can have a look at the actual query.

Comment: I did a var_dump and it came back "true". When I do a print on my $sql_update, I get: UPDATE users_sensitive SET password = '700b5b23b511d974fe9eeb17ad350b33', ch_password = '700b5b23b511d974fe9eeb17ad350b33' WHERE email_hash = 'ac24dab060a172d8c0b3679d8ae61cac' - There is no whitespace here. When I print the $result_update, it comes up with: 1

Comment: Also, `mysql_query` returns `true` on success or `false` on failure when doing `UPDATE` queries, it's not a count of affected rows. And an update that affects zero rows is still considered successful.

Answer (score 3):

No errors and no updates tells me that your `where` clause isn't matching anything. Make sure `$email_hash` doesn't have any leading or trailing whitespace and isn't being truncated.

A less likely possibility is that the update is part of a transaction that is being rolled back.

Another less likely possibility: are you connected to the right server?

Comment: I did a var_dump and it came back "true".  When I do a print on my $sql_update, I get: UPDATE users_sensitive SET password = '700b5b23b511d974fe9eeb17ad350b33', ch_password = '700b5b23b511d974fe9eeb17ad350b33' WHERE email_hash = 'ac24dab060a172d8c0b3679d8ae61cac' - There is no whitespace here.  When I print the $result_update, it comes up with: 1

Comment: what happens with `select * from users_sensitive where email_hash='$email_hash'`?

Comment: From my quick tests, Nothing happens...  My code is: `$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users_sensitive WHERE email_hash='$email_hash'";
  $result_select = mysql_query($sql_select);
   echo "test1";
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select)) {
    echo $user_sensitive_id = $row['user_sensitive_id'];
    echo $user_id = $row['user_id']; 
    echo "test";
   }` and I only receive the "test1" as though it's not seeing email_hash.  I have checked MULTIPLE times and the email hash exists in the database!

Comment: @Nathan - so we're back to the `where` clause not matching anything. Are you sure phpMyAdmin or whatever you're using to inspect the table is connected to the same server and database as your php code?

Comment: Also, yes - I include a database connect outside script.  Every page connects exactly the same and all pages are working correctly.  After checking DB names, Everything is exactly the same.

Comment: It must be the where clause.  When I enter the actual hash number, it will update just fine in the right spot.  When I have the hash number as a php variable, it doesn't recognize it, although, when I print it, it shows exactly the same thing.

Comment: how about with `"select * from users_sensitive where email_hash='" + mysql_real_escape_string($email_hash) + "'"`?

Comment: Have you checked for whitespaces, linebreaks et al?

Comment: I get "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1"

Comment: bernace is correct, the e-mail hash you are using does not match whatever is stored in the database! Could be because of truncation, trailing spaces, leading spaces, character encoding etc. You need to inspect the value you have in hte database and compare it with the value in your program.

Comment: Here is the value directly copy and pasted from the database with Quotation marks on the lead and trailing ends of what is copied "ac24dab060a172d8c0b3679d8ae61cac" as you can see, no white space.  Now, here is the value copied from a print off of the update query  'ac24dab060a172d8c0b3679d8ae61cac
'   It seems that there is a whole linebreak in there, but I don't understand where it is coming from.  I checked the POST value, and there is a line break in there.

Comment: Now, Here is the input value from the form:                          <input type="hidden" name="email_hash" value="<?= $email_hash; ?>"/>
I don't understand where a Linebreak can be coming from, though when I run this echo: `echo $email_hash = $_POST['email_hash'] . "test";` I get a break between the hash and the "test"!

Comment: Alright, I tried trim() and substr($email_hash, 0, -1) and they both did not work.  I have a mysterious line break after the post variable.  Any ideas?

Comment: Add the code that sets `$email_hash` that goes into the hidden input element to your question

Comment: Found it earlier in the code - I will answer and close it out.

Comment: I will "Answer" my question in 6 hours, I don't have the privileges to answer my own question yet.  In the mean time, the answer will be at the end of my question

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to bemace, James Anderson, VolkerK, alex and the others!

The problem was that there was a strange line break in the code creating whitespace that was not the same as on the database.

After backtracking, I noticed at the very beginning of my code on this page, I used a GET to get a hash number from the URL. While making a variable, during testing, I added a line break to the variable for testing purposes only. I (stupidly) left the line break in there. When using that variable in a hidden form field, it included the line break.

After taking the line break out of the first line, everything matched up and all is good.

If you are reading this and plan on posting later, Posting the entire code is probably worth it. This problem would have been fixed earlier if I had.

Again, Thank you to the quick responses and trouble shooting!